# How to maintain Laravel Dusk session over several windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Is there way to maintain session between Laravel Dusk opened windows? The test i am writing requires captcha login and then multiple windows testing parallaly some functionality.

see below code for explanation. right now below implementation opens new window but i have to type captcha twice on each instance. what i want to do is eliminate the login process and have the same session as the first window. The system is testing is very old php base system and its not written in laravel.

I am Using Laravel Framework 5.7.8 with Dusk 4.0 incase if you need version info. Thanks for

```
$this->browse(function ($first, $second) {
    $first->visit('login')
          ->type('username,'username')
          ->type('password,'xxxx')
          ->type('captcha_code,'') // wait for user to type captcha for 10 seconds
          ->pause(10000);
          ->press('#loginbutton');


    $second->visit('login')
          ->type('username,'username')
          ->type('password,'xxxx')
          ->type('captcha_code,'') // wait for user to type captcha for 10 seconds
          ->pause(10000);
          ->press('#loginbutton');

});
```

Comment: Try copying the session cookie to the other browser using `$browser->driver->manage()->getCookieNamed()` and `$browser->driver->manage()->addCookie()`.

Comment: Hey Jonas, thanks for the help but can you refer to some code which does that because i am bit confused here and couldn't find anything on dusk docs for what you are referring.

Comment: They are methods of the underlying [facebook/webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), I don't think there is a documentation. You should be able to send the result of `getCookieNamed()` (first browser) to `addCookie()` (second browser).

Comment: I found my answer via this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51111092/laravel-dusk-reuse-browser-with-its-session-and-cookies